# Rotate lines around their midpoint

Tags: graphics, geometric-transform

I am trying to rotate a series of lines by the same angle around their centre point.  Say each line is defined by a co-ordinate at each end, simplified example below of a typical dataset.

```
foo = {{{100, 25}, {150, 45}}, {{200, 45}, {240, 85}}};
```

Then the midpoint can be found by:-

```
boo = (#[[2]] - #[[1]])/2 + #[[1]] & /@ foo;
```

This is visualised using the code below:

```
Show[
Graphics[{Thick, Dashed, Black, Line /@ foo}],
Graphics[{Black, PointSize[Large],
Point[boo],
Table[{Black, Text[ToString[boo[[p]]], boo[[p]] + 2]}, {p, Length[boo]}]}]
]
```

[image]

I was hoping to create a series of transformations using RotationTransform such as below:

```
rot = RotationTransform[Pi/2, #] & /@ boo
```

Then mapping this across foo using MapThread, but I'm not sure which function I should be mapping across to make each line rotate by 90 degrees around its own centre point.

```
MapThread[?, {woo, rot}]
```

I think I'm close to what I want to achieve (or maybe not), but I can't quite seem to close it out. All suggestions welcome.

Comment: [`Midpoint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Midpoint.html),  introduced in 2019, can be used to find the midpoint. It works with a pair of points as well as a line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
grF := Function[{angle},
             Graphics[{Thick, Dashed, Black, Line@#,
             Red, GeometricTransformation[Line@#, 
                                     RotationTransform[angle, Mean@#]],
             Black, PointSize[Large], Point[Mean@#],
             Text[ToString[Mean@#], Mean@# + 2]} & /@ #] &]

grF[Pi/2]@foo
```

[image]

```
ListAnimate[Table[Show[grF[i]@foo, PlotRange -> {{50, 250}, {0, 100}}],
                 {i, -Pi,  Pi, Pi/32}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
foo = {{{100, 25}, {150, 45}}, {{200, 45}, {240, 85}}};
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{Line@#, Blue, Rotate[Line@#, t, Mean@#], Transparent, 
          Circle[Mean@#,EuclideanDistance @@ #/2]} & /@ foo], {t,0, 2 Pi}]
```

The transparent circles are there to pre-calculate the maximum Plot Range.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

1：

```
lines = {{{100, 25}, {150, 45}}, {{200, 45}, {240, 85}}};
f[{p1_, p2_}, theta_] := Module[{mid},
   mid = (p2 - p1)/2 + p1;
   RotationTransform[theta, mid][#] & /@ {p1, p2}
  ];
lines2 = f[#, Pi/6] & /@ lines;
Graphics[{Red, Line[lines], Blue, Line[lines2]}]
```

[image]

2：

```
lines = {{{100, 25}, {150, 45}}, {{200, 45}, {240, 85}}};
lines2 = RotationTransform[Pi/6, (#2 - #1)/2 + #1][{#1, #2}] & @@@ lines;
Graphics[{Red, Line[lines], Blue, Line[lines2]}]
```